# NivoSlider into wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, nivo-slider, shortcode

I´ve implemented manually NivoSlider into my wordpress theme. All working great, now I need to hide the div#NivoSlider from my index.php file so the slider will only show with the shortcode option. Either in other pages or widgets.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the Nivoslider code in a custom HTML widgets and call the widgets where you want to call like ....on Home page only or wherever you want or you can put the code in particular condition like is_frontpage() or is_page('about').

```
<?php if(is_front_page())
{ ?>
    <div id="nivo-slider">
        slider code
    </div>

<?php }
else
{ ?>
    <div id-"normal">

    </div>
<?php }

?>
```

Comment: I´m not sure i understand what you mean with that. Why should i use the "if (is something)"? All i need is to hide the NivoSlider DIV from everywhere, and have it show only when writing the shortcode either in a post, page or widget like [nivoslider category=test]. Thanks

Comment: I implemented it in the theme files, not as a plugin. Created custom post types and then the NivoSlider to work with those custom post types. Not sure if i´m answering your question correctly.

Comment: I dont think in this way shortcode will help you....short code works to invoke the plugin function...

Comment: Ah I see! In that case, it is not possible to use NivoSlider only with  shortcode and without the plugin? How could I achieve that? Thanks

Comment: what is your purpose how do you want to use this.....As per i understand you want put silder in post. The above solution is only for puting the slider on certain pages not on post

Comment: OK pure and simple. I want NivoSlider to show only in custom html widgets. Dont want to pre-configure it to show on certain pages or posts. For that to work I thought the shortcode method was the best solution since the client only has to write something like [nivo-slider] on any html widget and have the slider show where he wants.

Comment: was talking about my problem, not how to vote up or down lolz. Thanks Pramod on the help :)

Comment: Ohhh :) Just place that code in index.php of your wordpress theme